# Why won't this vim global command execute properly?

Tags: vim

In my ~/.vimrc on MacOSx I have:

```
let g:plantuml_executable_script='java -jar /Users/megan/Documents/plantuml.jar'
```

If I open Vim and do:

```
:! java -jar /Users/megan/Documents/plantuml.jar
```

the JAR file executes.

How do I execute it with the plantuml_executable_script command?

Answer (score 1):

You have just assigned a value to a variable, not executed it.

`let` command assigns value to a variable.

Run `:system (g:plantuml_executable_script)`

The variable inside system command will be executed.

Use this system command in the vimscript, or in .vimrc or directly execute it in the script's command line.